# How do I use @vue/test-utils to setProps and have them show up in the HTML?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I have the my code working in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-rxgfj?file=/src/App.vue) and now I am trying to write the test. However, When I try this...

```
test("Hello World", async () => {
  let list = [
    {
      name: "foo"
    }
  ];
  var data = {
    list
  };
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, data);
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("foo");
  expect(wrapper.html()).not.toContain("bar");
  list.push({
    name: "bar"
  });
  await wrapper.setProps({ list });
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("foo");
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("bar");
});
```

However, `expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("bar");` fails because it cannot fine the text. I can see it work using `setTimeout` so I am not sure what I am missing.

How do I see the prop changes in the html?

Comment: Could you provide the code of your component?

Comment: Your usage of `setProps()` here results in this warning: `[vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setProps() called with the same object of the existing list property. You must call wrapper.setProps() with a new object to trigger reactivity`. You don't actually need that line here because `list.push()` is reactive. Commenting out that line should be enough. I've verified your sandbox locally with `setProps()` removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is not expecting any props. When you mounting your component you are setting component's `data` property. And if you want to change it later in test after mounting you should call `setData`.

Also there is a mistake in your test: according to [docs](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#data) `data` must be a function.

With all being said your test should look like that:

```
test("Hello World", async () => {
  const list = [
    {
      name: "foo"
    }
  ];
  const data = () => {
    list
  };
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
    data
  });
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("foo");
  expect(wrapper.html()).not.toContain("bar");
  list.push({
    name: "bar"
  });
  await wrapper.setData({ list });
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("foo");
  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("bar");
});
```